# How to aggregate every 4 rows in row R

Tags: r, aggregate

I have data.frame contains 120 rows, which consists 3 columns :

[image]

I wanted to convert every 4 weeks into a month and sum total_score for each month based on the corresponding weeks.

it should be something like :

```
month SumScore
1      1
2      5
```

Comment: Images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8245406) and a [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit the question with the code you tried and with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (Note: `df` is the name of your dataset.)

Answer (score 2):

Using base R:

```
set.seed(0)

df <- data.frame(
    week = 1:120,
    value = sample(0:3, size = 120, replace = TRUE)
)

df$month <- (df$week - 1) %/% 4

aggregate(value ~ month, data = df, sum)
```

Output:

```
   month value
1      0     6
2      1     3
3      2     6
4      3     2
5      4     4
6      5     4
7      6     1
8      7     2
9      8     6
10     9     6
11    10     5
12    11    10
13    12     6
14    13     6
15    14     7
16    15     6
17    16     8
18    17     3
19    18     5
20    19     8
21    20     9
22    21     5
23    22     6
24    23     8
25    24     4
26    25     9
27    26     2
28    27     3
29    28     6
30    29     9
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  # turn `week` into batches of 4 values each: 
  mutate(month = (row_number() - 1) %/% 4) %>%
  # for each batch...:
  group_by(month) %>%
  # ...calculate the sum of `score`:
  summarise(ScoreSum = sum(score))
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  month ScoreSum
  <dbl>    <dbl>
1     0        1
2     1        5
```

Comment: I think you can use the week number column to create a month column, instead of using row_number() to overwrite the week column :-)

Comment: One other issue with using row_number() is that it assumes that there won't be any discontinuities in the data (i.e. it won't go 8, 9, 13), which would group in the case of row_number(), but not using week

Comment: No such issue is mentioned by OP

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions using a `cumsum` trick.

## Base R

```r
m <- 4L
month <- cumsum(rep(c(1L, rep(0L, m - 1L)), length.out = nrow(df1)))

aggregate(score ~ month, df1, sum)
#>   month score
#> 1     1     1
#> 2     2     5
#> 3     3     0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Package `dplyr`

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(
  library(dplyr)
)

m <- 4L
df1 %>%
  mutate(month = cumsum(rep(c(1L, rep(0L, m - 1L)), length.out = n()))) %>%
  group_by(month) %>%
  summarise(score = sum(score))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>   month score
#>   <int> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1
#> 2     2     5
#> 3     3     0
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Data

```r
df1 <- data.frame(
  week = 1:10,
  score = c(1,0,0,0,2,3,0,0,0,0),
  State = rep("Before", 10L)
)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>